# Typescript compile to modules.exports anonymous function

Tags: typescript

I currently have the following code in index.ts

```
export default (name: string): string => {
  return 'Hi ' + name;
}
```

The compiled index.js I must have as the outcome is

```
module.exports = (name) => {
  return 'Hi ' + name:
}
```

However, no matter what I try it always returns me with

```
exports.default = (function(name) => {
  return 'Hi' + name;
})
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist/cjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "listEmittedFiles": false,
    "listFiles": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "traceResolution": false,
    "types": ["node"],
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"
}
```

Comment: Change your `target` to `ES2015` or higher

Comment: It still returns exports.default instead of module.exports.

Comment: `exports` is an alias for `module.exports`, why do you need it to be exactly `module.exports`?

Comment: Because I need to compile it as a package make an import as `const varName = require("<myPachage>")("nameAsString")`.

Comment: ... Also, I can't make breaking changes, so having it to be `... require("<myPachage>").default("nameAsString")` won't be an option.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll write a response, tell me if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call an `export default` function simply with `require("package")()` because `export default` is translated in js as

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = (name) => {
    return "Hi " + name;
};
```

So you should call this arrow function with `require("package").default("name")`.

> Remember that [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#exports) is an alias for `module.exports`

There is however a "trick" to call it without the `.default`, rebinding the `export`:

```
export = (name: string): string => {
  return "Hi " + name;
};
```

This is translated to

```js
"use strict";
module.exports = (name) => {
    return "Hi " + name;
};
```

Let's give it a try:

```bash
$ node -e "console.log(require('./index')('rodolfo'))"
Hi rodolfo
```